# Populating ListView is slow, Fragment not loading smoothly

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, layout, layout-inflater

So I am working with AndroidStudio and writing my code in Kotlin.
I have a Fragment with a TabLayout and ViewPager that has 5 Tabs. Each tab contains another Fragment with a ListView and a ToggleButton. The ListViews all contain 10 items.
[Here is a screenshot, I'm not allowed to use embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mibA.png)

The problem is that the Fragment doesn't open smoothly, especially when opened first.

I think the problem lies within the implementation of the ListViewAdapter for the ListViews in the 5 Tabs, especially the getView function.
Here is the code for them:

```
    inner class TimetableListAdapter(
        private val _context : Context,
        private var fulldata : TimetableUtility.TimetableDay,
        var bWeek : Boolean,
        private var dayData : ArrayList<TimetableUtility.TimetableSubject> = fulldata[0],
        private val _resource : Int = R.layout.timetable_subject_element
    ) : ArrayAdapter<TimetableUtility.TimetableSubject>(_context, _resource, dayData){

        init {
            dayData = if(bWeek){
                fulldata[1]
            }else{
                fulldata[0]
            }
            Log.d("Timetable" , "Adapter init ")
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

            Log.d("Timetable" , "getView: $bWeek")

            val s : TimetableUtility.TimetableSubject = if(bWeek){
                dayData = fulldata[1]
                fulldata[1][position]
            }else{
                dayData = fulldata[0]
                fulldata[0][position]
            }

            val v =
                convertView
                    ?: LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(
                        _resource,
                        parent,
                        false
                    )

            v.editIcon.setOnClickListener {
                openEditDialog(this@TimetableDayFragment.context!!,s)
            }

            v.timetable_hour_number.text = (position + 1).toString()
            v.timetable_subject_title.text = s.name
            v.timetable_subject_room.text = s.room

            return v
        }
    }
```

I know that the implementation of a ViewHolder pattern would reduce the count of view searching calls, but I think that this wouldn't affect the initial generation.

I played a little bit with the Profiler in AndroidStudio and found out, that the getView method of my adapter takes about 20-30ms when running the application on a virtual machine on my pc. When running the application on my Samsung device (Galaxy A6, not that old) it more, as the delay is bigger. I didn't use the profiler with it yet.

**Is my assumption, that the lag results from the getView method right and if yes, do you have any suggestions or ideas how to improve that?**

If that will help, here is the code of the adapter for the ViewPager:

```
    inner class TimetableFragmentAdapter(
        context : Context,
        fm : FragmentManager,
        private val totalTabs : Int
    ) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm,totalTabs){

        private val dayTitles = arrayOfNulls<String>(5)
        private var sdf =
            SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.getDefault())
        private var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()!!

        init{
            for (i in 0..4) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i + 2)
                dayTitles[i] = sdf.format(calendar.time)
            }
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return totalTabs
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return dayTitles[position]
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            when(position){
                0 -> return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
                1 -> return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
                2 -> return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
                3 -> return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
                4 -> return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
            }
            return TimetableDayFragment(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, this@TimetableFragment)
        }
```

and the on create code of the inner fragments, that are used each of the tabs

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable_inner_fragment,container,false)

        adapter = TimetableListAdapter(context!!, TimetableUtility.timetable.get(day), root.weekSwitch.isChecked)
        root.timetable_list.adapter = adapter

        root.weekSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener{
                it, selected ->
            (root.timetable_list.adapter as TimetableListAdapter).bWeek = selected
            (root.timetable_list.adapter as TimetableListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        return root
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help and ideas in advance.
If you need any more code or information, please just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TimetableFragmentAdapter` override `destroyItem()`

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
// destroy your fragment view here
}
```

Follow this question [How to remove fragment from fragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758799/how-to-remove-fragment-from-fragmentpageradapter)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How exactly should I destroy the fragment? 
And can you explain how that helps to solve the problem? I didn't get it yet.