# PagerAdapter ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$SavedState

Tags: android, android-viewpager, parcelable, android-pageradapter

I am using a custom view pager with a PagerAdapter and I get the following crash when I have "Don't keep activities" turned on:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$SavedState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$SavedState
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2675)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1967)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2321)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ao.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:74)
at maps.ei.bu.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.r.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IUiSettingsDelegate$zza.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:66)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.getMap(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb$6728a24f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzvu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zzdY(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zzdY(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.android.fragments.MapFragment.newMap(SourceFile:2096)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1789)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:955)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState$2563266(SourceFile:1120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(SourceFile:1929)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:547)
at com.activities.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:255)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

instantiateItem from my PagerAdapter looks like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    mViewPagerLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_pager, collection, false);

    mViewPagerLayout.setTag("pos" + position);
    collection.addView(mViewPagerLayout);
    return mViewPagerLayout;
}
```

CustomViewPager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


// more code
```

}

xml where custom view pager is being used:

```
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    class="com.android.lib.views.WrapperView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.android.lib.views.CustomViewPager
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
      android:paddingTop="0dp"
      android:paddingBottom="0dp"
      android:paddingRight="20dp"
      android:visibility="gone"
      tools:visibility="visible"/>
 </view>
```

I have looked at solutions here [ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$SavedState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381470/classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling-android-support-v4-view-viewpagersav) but these are Fragments but I am using a View and PagerAdapter to keep it light weight. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: I was able to move forward by setting `android:saveEnabled="false"` for the view pager but it is not ideal solution. I would still like to be able solve this issue and save the state of the view pager

Comment: any updates about this issue..?