# BadParcelableException:ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState

Tags: android

I've migrated to SDK Android 27.1.0 3 days ago, and there are some crashs like this one, I can't understand why. It appears (currently) on Android 8 and 6.

```
BadParcelableException ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint

android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2916)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2842)
android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2745)
android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:3114)
android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked (BaseBundle.java:273)
android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:226)
android.os.BaseBundle.putBoolean (BaseBundle.java:532)
arrow_right
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint (Fragment.java:960)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem (FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:121)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem (ViewPager.java:1004)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1218)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1086)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run (ViewPager.java:267)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:655)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is my adapter:

```
public abstract class CalendarPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(CalendarPagerAdapter.class);

    protected DateTime mDateTime;
    private final int mCount;
    protected int mTodayPosition;

    public static class CalendarContext {
        public int mRange; // range = nb of days supported
        public int mTodayPosition; // Today index in this area
        public int mCurrentWeek; // Week number of today
        public DateTime mFrom, mTo; // Compute from and to datetimes
        public boolean mIsSundayFirstDay;

        public CalendarContext(int area, int todayPosition, DateTime from, DateTime to,
                               int currentWeek, boolean isSundayFirstDay) {
            mRange = area;
            mTodayPosition = todayPosition;
            mFrom = from;
            mTo = to;
            mCurrentWeek = currentWeek;
            mIsSundayFirstDay = isSundayFirstDay;
        }
    }

    public static CalendarContext computeAreaAndTodayPosition(int initialArea, int initialTodayPosition) {
        // Compute min / max dates from now
        DateTime from = new DateTime().minusDays(initialArea - initialTodayPosition).dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
        DateTime to = new DateTime().plusDays(initialTodayPosition).dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue();

        boolean isSundayFirstDay = false;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(CompatUtils.getLocale(false));
        if (calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            isSundayFirstDay = true;
            from = from.minusDays(1);
            to = to.minusDays(1);
        }

        LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "from dt=" + from.toString());
        LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "to dt=" + to.toString());

        // Compute nb days area supported
        int daysRange = daysBetween(from, to).getDays() + 1;
        LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "daysRange=" + daysRange);

        // Compute today position
        int todayPosition = daysBetween(from, DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays() + 1;
        LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "todayPosition=" + todayPosition);

        int currentWeek = DateTime.now().getWeekOfWeekyear() - from.getWeekOfWeekyear();
        LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "currentWeek=" + currentWeek);

        return new CalendarContext(daysRange, todayPosition, from, to, currentWeek, isSundayFirstDay);
    }

    public CalendarPagerAdapter(FragmentManager mgr, int count, int todayPosition) {
        super(mgr);
        mDateTime = DateTime.now();
        mCount = count;
        mTodayPosition = todayPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public boolean isTodayPosition(int position) {
        return computeDifferenceDays(position) == 0;
    }

    public boolean isPastPosition(int position) {
        return computeDifferenceDays(position) < 0;
    }

    public boolean isFuturPosition(int position) {
        return computeDifferenceDays(position) > 0;
    }

    protected int computeDifferenceDays(int position) {
        return position - getCalendarTodayPosition();
    }

    public long convertPositionToMs(int position) {
        return convertPositionToMs(mDateTime, position);
    }

    public long convertMinPositionToMs() {
        return convertPositionToMs(mDateTime, 0);
    }

    public long convertMaxPositionToMs() {
        return convertPositionToMs(mDateTime, mCount - 1);
    }

    public String convertPositionToDate(int position) {
        return TimeUnits.dateTimeToDateServer(new DateTime(convertPositionToMs(position)));
    }

    public long convertPositionToMs(DateTime datime, int position) {
        int dayNum = computeDifferenceDays(position);
        if (dayNum < 0)
            return datime.minusDays(Math.abs(dayNum)).getMillis();
        else if (dayNum > 0)
            return datime.plusDays(Math.abs(dayNum)).getMillis();
        else
            return datime.getMillis();
    }

    public int convertMsToPosition(long millis) {
        DateTime dtReceived = new DateTime(millis).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
        return convertDateTimeToPosition(dtReceived);
    }

    public int convertDateTimeToPosition(DateTime dtReceived) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
        int nbDays = daysBetween(now, dtReceived).getDays();
        return getCalendarTodayPosition() + nbDays;
    }

    public int getCalendarTodayPosition() {
        return mTodayPosition;
    }

    public void shiftWithOffset(WeekDatePicker weekDatePicker, TextView weekDatePickerDayTextView,
                                DateTime currentSelectedDate, int offset) {
        if (offset < 0 && mTodayPosition > 0) mTodayPosition += offset;
        mDateTime = DateTime.now();
        weekDatePicker.refreshTodayPosition();
        weekDatePickerDayTextView.setText(TimeUnits.dateTimeToString(
                currentSelectedDate, true, true, true, true, true));
    }
}
```

Have you got some ideas guys to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: would you share your code?

Comment: Did you look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/36811037/3145960

Comment: @MohammodHossain: which code? I don't know where this crash appears...

Comment: Did you use parseable or Serialize in your model

Comment: This normally happens when library version doesn't match.

Comment: Check your model class, and if you have implemented Parcelable in your model/pojo class please cross check for any mistakes

Comment: i would say please share you `fragment adapter` code if you are using

Comment: @AbdulKawee I've updated my initial post. Thank you!

Comment: @anthony have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381470/classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling-android-support-v4-view-viewpagersav

Comment: @anthony have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem :/

Comment: @Fori absolutely no... :( I've downgraded to 27.0.2. There are some mistakes into 27.1.0 ...

Comment: @anthony can you help me and answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328178/how-to-downgrade-android-support-library

Answer (score 8):

@XJIOP said is correct i also have same issue on my production, but i was unable to find what the crash, i followed @XJIOP path and produce the bug,i resolved the bug by updating the compact version
from

> appcompat 27.1.0  to  27.1.1

since i am using proguard i also added the following line to my proguard

add the following line  to proguard if you are using proguard on your production build else ignore

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

After adding the pro guard line and updating the compact lib i was able to fix the issue and the bug hasent reported yet on my updated production build.
hope this will help some others

Comment: Thanks. The proguard setting helped me with another problem similar to this.

Answer (score 6):

Same issues after update android library to 27.1.0

My viewPager has 3 tabs, this crash occurs if I select first or last tab, then after loss activity and returning to viewPager chose another tab got this crash.

Tested with 2 tabs has no crash.

My fix is

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

and crash is gone

**EDIT**

Updating to 27.1.1 has resolved issue

Comment: i see a bug report filed here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74130311 . can you all add to it so they can increase the priority.