# How to downgrade android support library

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I updated sdk to 27.1.0 but now i want to downgrade to 27.0.2
My build.gradle contains these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cz.my.package"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 73
        versionName "1.1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 6
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    implementation 'in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'cz.martinforejt:swipetohidelayout:1.0.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But android studio says, that it founds some lib with version 27.1.0 and all must have same version.
Another problem is that i cant find 27 folder inside `sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/`

How can i downgrade support libraries?

Comment: "I updated sdk to 27.1.0 but now i want to downgrade to 27.0.2" -- why? "But android studio says, that it founds some lib with version 27.1.0 and all must have same version" -- if cleaning your project does not help, then something else in your `dependencies` is looking for 27.1.0. "Another problem is that i cant find 27 folder inside sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/" -- the Android Support library comes from the `google()` repository.

Comment: Downgrade because of this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228979/
So where is support library stored, i checked: sdk/extras/google

Comment: The repository is at https://maven.google.com.

Comment: I mean where is stored on my disk, for older versions i have folders like this: sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7

Comment: It isn't stored in the SDK. The official location is https://maven.google.com. This is not significantly different than getting dependencies from JCenter or Maven Central. In all those cases, Gradle will cache copies of the artifacts as needed.

Comment: Can edit your answer and paste full build.gradle code

Comment: @KMI sure added

Comment: Delete this line buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'. And project->clean project

Comment: @KMI does not helped :(

Comment: Can you build project without error?

Comment: No, i get `com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives`

Comment: So i found problem in this dependency: `com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0` is there any way to use it with 27.0.2 version?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: Thanks i found this solution:
`implementation ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166995/discussion-between-kmi-and-fori).