# ViewPager switch FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have got a `ViewPager` which is populated by a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I want to change from the first adapter two another. The problem is that all pages which were loaded before (while having the first adapter) are still the old ones.

I looked at the source code of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and guess the problem occurs because of the `instatiateItem()` implementation. Using the tag, which has position and conatiner id in it, the method checks if there is already a `Fragment` at the position. When there is a `Fragment` with this tag it is attached. The container id and position do not change when setting a new adapter so it finds the old `Fragment`s.

Do you know a way to remove all old fragments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realized that the Fragment tag uses an id, obtained by `getItemId()` and not the position. To solve my issue I have overwritten `getItemId()` and use totally different ids in the different `FragmentPagerAdapter`s.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mPagerId*100+position;
}
```

mPagerId is an unique integer that is assigned in the constructor. If you have more than 100 pages you should replace 100 with 1000.

Comment: @AntonM. It works very well on HTC legend with android 2.2, Thanks gabriel

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will cause a memory leak since all the previous page fragments will stay in memory inside the fragment manager - you can easily check that by using getFragmentSupportManager().getFragments().
Generating new ids will just force the PagerAdapter to create new pages without removing the ones with the old ids...