# Tabs + ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter - How to remove fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using the "Tabs + Swipe" project and I'm having a difficult time removing a fragment.

**Steps I'm doing:**

1. Remove tab from database
2. Remove tab from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter data source
3. Remove tab from the actionBar.
4. Remove fragment using Support FragmentManager.

**The problem:**
After I perform the remove, for some reason, I can still scroll to the right and see an empty fragment. I can't select it, it just bounces back.
It seems like the fragment is not being removed but rather changes its position to the tag from the left.

**My Adapter:**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_TAB_POSITION, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabsList.get(position).getTitle();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment)object).getFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove((Fragment)object);
            trans.commit();
        }
    }
```

**My remove method (called from within the fragment):**

```
public void removeTab() {
            mTabTableHandler.deleteTab(tab.getId()); //db
            tabsList.remove(tabPosition); //data source
            actionBar.removeTabAt(tabPosition); // actionbar

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit(); // support fragmentmanager

            tabsList = mTabTableHandler.query(); //requery db
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify adapter
        }
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can find the answer here -
[Remove Fragment Page from ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android)

it seems what missing in your code is overwriting of the following adapter's method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

explanation why such "weird" solution works you can find in the answer to the question in the link I provided you.

Comment: saved me, great solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeAllFragments(ViewGroup container) {
        /*
         * keep this line because section pager adapter has
         * the bug to not delete the last fragment completely
         * -> so we add an empty fragment
         */
        int iStart = 0;

        addFragment(new Fragment());
        Fragment frag;
        int size = fragments.size();
        for (int iPos = iStart; iPos < size; iPos++) {
            frag = getItem(iStart);
            if (frag.isAdded()) {
                destroyItem(container, iStart, frag);
            }
            fragments.remove(frag);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```