# How to dynamically remove page from ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

How to destroy view properly in ViewPager? I created app that contains a ListFragment which is populated with list items. On a list item click, new fragment is created and added to FragmentPagerAdapter. Everything works fine until i try to remove view from ViewPager. Calling method mViewPager.removeViewAt(position); leaves empty blank page at given position. If i scroll to another page after removing view and scroll back to that empty page application crashes.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClicked(int position) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Listitem clicked! position: " + position);

    FragmentContent fragment = new FragmentContent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", Directory.urls[position]);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(Directory.boards[position]).setTag(fragment).setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab, true);
    // Call this method to update ActionBar
    invalidateOptionsMenu();

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem() position: " + position);
        // ActionBar tag contains fragment
        Fragment frag = (Fragment)mActionBar.getTabAt(position).getTag();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mActionBar.getTabCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        // Remove page and tab at given position
        mViewPager.removeViewAt(position);
        // ActionBar tag contains fragment
        Fragment frag = (Fragment)mActionBar.getTabAt(position).getTag();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(frag).commit();
        mActionBar.removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(position));
        // Update options menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.menu_close:
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected() close thread button pressed!");
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.destroyItem(null, mActionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition(), null);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Log:

```
2-24 20:41:32.578: I/FragmentList(10185): Item clicked: 4
02-24 20:41:32.593: I/MainActivity(10185): SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem() position: 1
02-24 20:41:32.593: I/FragmentContent(10185): FragmentContent onAttach
02-24 20:41:32.601: I/FragmentContent(10185): FragmentContent onResume()
// This is the point where i try to destroy page
02-24 20:41:47.273: I/MainActivity(10185): onOptionsItemSelected() close thread button pressed!
02-24 20:41:47.289: I/FragmentContent(10185): FragmentContent onPause()
02-24 20:41:47.289: I/FragmentContent(10185): FragmentContent onDestroy

// This is the point i scroll back to that empty page
02-24 20:42:09.546: W/dalvikvm(10185): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab21f8)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:801)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1010)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:495)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:476)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.MoTo.ylilauta.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:198)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:512)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:441)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.MoTo.ylilauta.MainActivity.onListItemClicked(MainActivity.java:147)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.MoTo.ylilauta.FragmentList.onListItemClick(FragmentList.java:48)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1082)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2625)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3296)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
02-24 20:42:09.546: E/AndroidRuntime(10185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 20:42:11.632: I/Process(10185): Sending signal. PID: 10185 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The only way that worked for me was https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944013/8874312