# Orientation change with viewPager inside FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, screen-orientation

I'm trying to build an app that shows a book in portrait and landscape mode. So obviously there's 1 page showed in portrait and 2 in landscape. Each of the mode works pretty good but when i change the orientation from portrait to landscape the viewPager try to get 2 pages from the portrait mode instead of trying to get 2 double pages from the landscape mode ...
In fact **FragmentStatePagerAdapter keeps The 2 fragments created in portrait and uses them before creating 2 double page for the landscape mode**. If i switch again in portrait mode, FragmentStatePagerAdapter uses the 2 fragments previously created in landscape mode so i see again 1 double page instead of 1 single page etc.. if i continue switching orientation, i get an OutOfMemoryError due to the fact that FragmentStatePagerAdapter never flush it's fragments on orientation change.

Here's 2 use cases for easier understanding :

- i launch viewPager in portrait mode
- i see page 1                                   ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 2              ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 3              ok
- i rotate the screen to landscape mode
- i see page 3                                   wrong
- i swipe to right and i see page 4              wrong
- i swipe to right and i see page 5 and 6        ok
- i launch viewPager in portrait mode
- i see page 1                                   ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 2              ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 3              ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 4              ok
- i swipe to right and i see page 5              ok
- i rotate the screen to landscape mode
- i see page 5                                   wrong
- i swipe to left and i see page 4              wrong
- i swipe to left and i see page 2 and 3        ok

  ```
  public class PlayerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private Intent mIntent;
  private ViewPager mPortraitPager;
  private ViewPager mLandscapePager;
  private Boolean mIsLandscape;
  private String mKey;
  private int mNbPages;
  private int mNbDoublePages;
  private PageFactory mPageFactory;
  private DoublePageFactory mDoublePageFactory;
  private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onStop(){
      super.onStop();
      mPagerAdapter = null;
      mDoublePageFactory = null;
      mPageFactory = null; 
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_player);
      mIntent = getIntent();
      mKey = mIntent.getStringExtra("key");
      mNbPages = mIntent.getIntExtra("nbPages", 0);
      mNbDoublePages = DoublePageFactory.getDoublePageNumFromPageNum(mNbPages);

      Resources res = getResources();
      mIsLandscape = (res.getConfiguration().orientation == 1) ? false : true;
      mPortraitPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.portraitPager);
      mLandscapePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.landscapePager);

      mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

      if (mIsLandscape) {
          mDoublePageFactory = new DoublePageFactory(this, mKey, mNbPages, res.getInteger(R.integer.nb_page_columns), res.getInteger(R.integer.nb_page_columns));
          mPortraitPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mLandscapePager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
          mPortraitPager.setAdapter(null);
      } else {
          mPageFactory = new PageFactory(this, mKey, this.mNbPages, res.getInteger(R.integer.nb_page_columns), res.getInteger(R.integer.nb_page_columns));
          mLandscapePager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mPortraitPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
          mLandscapePager.setAdapter(null);
      }
  }


  public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

      public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
          super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          if(mIsLandscape){
              Fragment doublePageFragment = new DoublePageFragment();
              args.putInt(DoublePageFragment.ARG_DOUBLEPAGE_NUM, position + 1);
              doublePageFragment.setArguments(args);
              return doublePageFragment;
          }else{
              Fragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
              args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUM, position + 1);
              pageFragment.setArguments(args);
              return pageFragment;
          }
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return (mIsLandscape) ? mNbDoublePages:mNbPages;

      }

              /* j'ai essayé cette méthode mais ça ne fonctionne pas :( */
      @Override
      public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
              FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
              FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
              trans.remove((Fragment) object);
              trans.commit();

          super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemPosition(Object object){
          return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
      }

      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
          return "p." + position + 1;
      }
  }

  public boolean isLandscape() {
      return mIsLandscape;
  }

  public ImageView getSinglePage(int position) {
      return mPageFactory.getPage(position);
  }


  public LinearLayout getDoublePage(int position) {
      return mDoublePageFactory.getDoublePage(position);
  }
  }


  public class PageFragment extends Fragment {    
  private PlayerFragmentActivity mPlayerFragmentActivity;
  public static final String ARG_PAGE_NUM = "page_number";
  public static final String ARG_WOBOOK_DIRECTORY = "book_directory";
  public static final String ARG_NB_PAGE_COLUMNS = "nb_page_columns";
  public static final String ARG_NB_PAGE_ROWS = "nb_page_rows";

  @Override
  public ImageView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mPlayerFragmentActivity = ((PlayerFragmentActivity) getActivity());
      return mPlayerFragmentActivity.getSinglePage(getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE_NUM));
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop(){
      super.onStop();
      mPlayerFragmentActivity = null;
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  public class DoublePageFragment extends Fragment {
  private PlayerFragmentActivity mPlayerFragmentActivity;
  public static final String ARG_DOUBLEPAGE_NUM = "double_page_number";
  public static final String ARG_WOBOOK_DIRECTORY = "book_directory";
  public static final String ARG_NB_PAGE_COLUMNS = "nb_page_columns";
  public static final String ARG_NB_PAGE_ROWS = "nb_page_rows";

  @Override
  public LinearLayout onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mPlayerFragmentActivity = ((PlayerFragmentActivity) getActivity());
      return mPlayerFragmentActivity.getDoublePage(getArguments().getInt(ARG_DOUBLEPAGE_NUM));
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop(){
      super.onStop();
      mPlayerFragmentActivity = null;
  }
  }
  ```

i've read that the FragmentManager in the framework takes care of saving the state and restore any active fragments that the pager has made. So i guess that when the orientation changes, the FragmentManager says

> Hey ! I already have 2 items created so i don't need to create news,
>   lets get them

But in fact it gets the 2 items (page/double page) from the old orientation mode. So i need to fnd a way to delete the fragments saved by the FragmentManager when the orientation change occurs.

I've also tested [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android). The problem seems to be related to [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19001)

Best regards

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try to limit orientation to either portrait or Landscape mode.Because we can use view pager only in exact mode.