# Strange behavior when orientations change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

im having some issues with screen onrientations changes..
i have my MainActivity with a tablayout and recycle view. Works all perfectly when i run my app, but when i turn my device to landscape, my methods dont get called, i have an ViewPagerAdapter, the method getItem dont get called when the screen changes..

MainActivity:

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
 viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
 viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

the contructor, and the getCount method enters normal, but getItem doesnt.
im doing something wrong or forgeting something ?

i need that my method getItem(..) from ViewPagerAdapter gets called..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using onRestoreInstanceState() take a look at the documentation on handling configuration changes. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: thank you ! just add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" and the activity and it works

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments are kept alive during the orientation change, and hence they don't need to be recreated afterwards. If they don't need to be recreated, `getItem()` won't be called.

See [this answer to the question "When is FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem called?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339534/930640).