# FragmentStatePagerAdapter - Reset data set

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

This is the scenario:

- the adapter already contains data
- i need to clear the old data set and add a new one fetched from the server

The 'clear()' works removing all the items but then the adapter gets re-populated with the old fragments instead of the new ones.

Thanks in advance for helping.

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
     private ArrayList<MyFragment> mFragments;
     ...
     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
         return mFragments.get(pos);
     }
     ...
     public void clear() {
         mFragments.clear();
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public void addItems(List<MyItem> items) {
         for(MyItem it : items) {
             mFragments.add(MyFragment.newInstance(it));
         }
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
         MyFragment fi = (MyFragment) object;
         int idx = mFragments.indexOf(fi);
         if (idx >= 0) {
             return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
         } else {
             return POSITION_NONE;
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

---

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MyFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ...

    private void resetItems(List<MyItem> items) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addItems(items);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you keep in `stack`?

Comment: @gunar sorry, stack is actually mFragments, I'll edit the text

Comment: Why don't you try to recreate the adapter?

Comment: @gunar edited, there's no stack

Comment: You're actually keeping the references to your fragments both in your `MyFragmentAdapter` directly and indirectly in parent `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` indirectly

Comment: Your question seems to have [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399127/1051783)

Comment: @gunar returning always POSITION_NONE isn't the solution, my version is correct. The problem is when re-adding the fragments, the adapter is restoring the old fragments...

Comment: I don't have any other option to suggest than to try to recreate the adapter and use the newly instance instead ...