# How to remove pages in Android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add/remove dynamically `fragments` in a `ViewPager` following a button click, but if I `remove` the fragment (a form) by clicking on back button, and add the fragment again, the form has kept its data (EditText not empty).

Here is my adapter :

```
package com.thomas.playlists.viewPager;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    ArrayList<Fragment> mList = null;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        mList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }

    public void add(Fragment fragment)
    {
        mList.add(fragment);
    }

    public void removeLast()
    {
        if(mList.size() > 1)
            mList.remove(getCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        return mList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

Adding proccess used twice (in main Activity) :

```
PlaylistFragment playlistFragment = new PlaylistFragment();

mViewPagerAdapter.add(playlistFragment);
mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1, true);
```

Removing a page (still in main Activity) :

```
mViewPagerAdapter.removeLast();
mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1, true);
```

How can I remove the fragment properly ?

**EDIT :** I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android#answer-10399127) but the form isn't reseted;

**EDIT 2 :** After instanciating the second fragment, its `onCreate()` method isn't called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android

Comment: See my edit, it's not working :/.

Comment: try  mViewPager.setadapter(mViewPagerAdapter) after notifydatasetchanged

Comment: i have tried and its working

Comment: @koutuk Nothing happens at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extend **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**, and override `getItemPosition` methode:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    //... your existing code

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int position = mList.indexOf(object);
        return position == -1 ? POSITION_NONE : position;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. If I add a new fragment (different from my form) to the ViewPager, the form is still displayed instead of the new fragment.

Comment: also, with FragmentPagerAdapter not working, but with FragmentStatePagerAdapter  it's working. Why?

Comment: Thank you, You saved my day