# add/remove fragment in viewpager using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter to load 4 fragments initially. Now i have another fragment which i want to show only when a click is performed (let say from a button inside other fragments) , and every time that fragment is bring to front, new data of should be in it. So now what should be my logic to do this?

**My FragmentPagerAdapater**

```
public class SmallViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Fragment> allFragments;

public SmallViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
        ArrayList<Fragment> allFragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.allFragments = allFragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return allFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allFragments.size();
} }
```

**Defining my adapter and adding it to viewpager**

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> frags = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
private SmallViewPagerAdapter vpAdapter;
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
frags.add(new MapContainerFragment(this));
frags.add(new FavoriteContainerFragment(this));
frags.add(new AllOffersFragment(this));
frags.add(new RegisterFragment(this));
vpAdapter = new SmallViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                frags);
viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
```

Now for some reason i have to put **setOffscreenPageLimit(3)** because i dont want my other fragments to reload when ever they brought back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution i have found for this is to add my 5 fragments on initialization of viewpager

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> frags = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
private SmallViewPagerAdapter vpAdapter;
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
frags.add(new MapContainerFragment(this));
frags.add(new FavoriteContainerFragment(this));
frags.add(new AllOffersFragment(this));
frags.add(new RegisterFragment(this));
frags.add(new DetailFragment(this));
vpAdapter = new SmallViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                frags);
viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
```

and created a static function for updating the view on every click

```
public static void updateView(Context context, String offerId) {

    offer = new DBHandler(context).getOffersById(offerId);
    if (offer != null) {

        offerName.setText(offer.getTitle());

        offerSave.setText(offer.getListTitle());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                Constants.URLHelper.getUrlForOfferImage(offer.getId(),
                        offer.getLogoId()), offerImage);

        detailText.setText(Html.fromHtml(offer.getDetailDesc().replace(
                "COLOR=\"#0B333C\"", " ")));

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Offer detail found!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and on the button click i just change the current selected page of the viewpager.

**NOTE:** I know its a bad approach but that's all I can come up for the solution to my problem. If someone have a better idea or thinks that this approach isn't better, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

you should change this method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberOfFragmentsToShow;
}
```

`numberOfFragmentsToShow` is an `int` variable you change when you want to show more/less fragments

keep a reference to an instance of `SmallViewPagerAdapter` and when you are chaining the number of fragments, make sure you call  `smallViewPagerAdapterInstance.notifyDataSetChanged();` for the changes to take effect.

Alternately you could be adding/removing items from the arraylist of fragments, but you must call `smallViewPagerAdapterInstance.notifyDataSetChanged();` to see the changes.

Comment: firstly thanks for reply, secondly, for now i have created a function in my adapter `public void addFrag(Fragment frag) {

  allFragments.add(frag);
  notifyDataSetChanged();

 }` by which i can add a fragment easily but the problem is i cant remove the fragment by calling this function `public void removeFrag() {
  
  allFragments.remove(allFragments.size() - 1);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }`

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android

Comment: i have, i think the problem is that i am using `setOffscreenLimit(4)` which isnt letting me destroy and add new fragment ... and i cant remove this caz i dont want other fragments to reload when they brought back to front.

Comment: I will check my code tomorrow, but I am pretty sure I did what I have told you. I was only disabling the swipe by returning a lower number of fragments than it should have been if some conditions were not met. I have also made a custom circle page inidicator. That guy was also fooled in the same way, he was drawing a lower number of circles than he should.

Answer (score 0):

Add or remove fragment in viewpager dynamically:

- Call `setupViewPager(viewPager)` on activity start.

To load a different fragment, call `setupViewPagerCustom(viewPager)`:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new fragmnet1(), "HOME");
    adapter.addFrag(new fragmnet2(), "SERVICES");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupViewPagerCustom(ViewPager viewPager)
{

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(new fragmnet3(), "Contact us");
    adapter.addFrag(new fragmnet4(), "ABOUT US");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Viewpageradapter, handles the views

static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```