# IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My ViewPager will delete a fragment upon button click. But when I click delete, I get "canot change tag" error. Browsing through other similar questions, it was either a problem with the getItem, or getCount in the PagerAdapter, which I think my implementation is fine. Please advice.

This is the fragment to be deleted

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    displayActivity = (DisplayActivity) getActivity();
    initView();
}
 Button delete = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dont_show_button_1);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayActivity.removeCurrentFragment(count-1);
        }
    });
```

My PagerAdapter is

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

long baseId = 0;
public static List<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    fragmentArrayList.add(new FragmentOne());
    fragmentArrayList.add(new FragmentTwo());
    fragmentArrayList.add(new FragmentThree());
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // give an ID different from position when position has been changed
    return baseId + position;
}

/**
 * Notify that the position of a fragment has been changed.
 * Create a new ID for each position to force recreation of the fragment
 * @param n number of items which have been changed
 */
public void notifyChangeInPosition(int n) {
    // shift the ID returned by getItemId outside the range of all previous fragments
    baseId += getCount() + n;
}
}
```

This is the activity that hosts the ViewPager

```
public class DisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
String TAG = "DisplayActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.db_layout);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}

public void removeCurrentFragment(int position){
    pagerAdapter.fragmentArrayList.remove(position);
    pagerAdapter.notifyChangeInPosition(1);
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e(TAG, "in removeCurrentFragment");
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment FragmentTwo{170c98f1 #1 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:1}: was android:switcher:2131492973:1 now android:switcher:2131492973:3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Changing it to

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

enabled correct deletion.

This can be attributed to "FragmentStatePagerAdapter disposes of views that fall outside the current and traversable views."
As suggested to this post
[Remove Fragment Page from ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your code i think your count value may be wrong.

```
Button delete = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dont_show_button_1);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // here
        displayActivity.removeCurrentFragment(count-1);
        //change to
      displayActivity.removeCurrentFragment(adapter.getCount()-1);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.Please post your whole code like where you getting the value of count variable. Post whole Code if Solution Does not Solve Your Problem .
Refer here for example:-  https://androidruler.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/working-with-viewpager-as-a-images-slider/

Comment: Count is simply 1 for fragment 1, 2 for fragment 2, 3 for fragment 3