# Update/Reload fragment with new data received from activity with TabLayout and FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My application consists of an ActivityHome using `TabLayout` and `SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter` to insert placeholder in two internal fragment (FragmentLeft and FragmentRight).

The ActivityHome loads data from the database and passes them through bundle in the two fragment using the method getItem from the SectionsPagerAdapter  (pretty much a base SectionsPagerAdapter)

The FragmentRight creates a popup that contains within it another fragment (FragmentPopup). This fragment give at the user the possibility to make change and save all to the database through UPDATE query

This data is displayed in FragmentLeft and FragmentRight, I would like update them when the database is updated via FragmentPopup.

For this I defined a interface in the FragmentPopup (`interfaceDataFragmentPopUpToActivity`), that interface is implemented in the HomeActivity. Through this interface the ActivityHome sees that the data has been modified and updates the datas that will then be passed at the two fragment. This update of the datas is performed in ActivityHome with the implementation of the method of my interface.
In addition I have overwritten the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of my SectionsPagerAdapter class for try to update the two fragment.
The problem is that I can not recharge the fragments (I'm interested above all the FragmentLeft) properly.

This is a little part of the code of the MainActivity

```
public class ActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity InterfaceDataFragmentPopUpToActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private FragmentLeft fragmentLeft;
    private FragmentRight fragmentRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        ...
    }

    //method from my interface
    @Override
    public void updateData(Boolean changeData) {
        if (changeData) {

            ...
            Load data from database;
            ...

            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("dataPass", dataPass);
            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    //My SectionsPagerAdapter inside the java file of the ActivityHome
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private Bundle bundleAdapter;

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle bundleAdapter) {
            super(fm);
            this.bundleAdapter = bundleAdapter;
        }


        //this is one of the latest tests carried out to update the Fragment
        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
            this.bundleAdapter = bundle;
            fragmentLeft = new FragmentLeft();
            FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentLeft.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fragmentLeft);
            ft.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            fragmentLeft = new FragmentLeft();
            fragmentRight = new FragmentRight();
            fragmentLeft.setArguments(bundleAdapter);
            fragmentRight.setArguments(bundleAdapter);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return fragmentLeft;
                case 1:
                    return fragmentRight;
                default:
                    return fragmentLeft;
            }
        } 

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Replace blank spaces with image icon
            SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(tabTitles[position]);
            return sb;
        }
    }
```

The ActivityHome layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

**SOLVED**

i have find the solution in this post [Remove Fragment Page from ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android)

I have change `FragmentPageAdapter` with `FragmentStatePageAdapater

and Override this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
//FragmentLeft is the class for the first fragment in the view
//recreate only FragmentLeft
    if (object instanceof FragmentLeft) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I propose again the explanation

### Why this solution works

**Overriding getItemPosition():**

When `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called, the adapter calls the `notifyChanged()` method of the `ViewPager` which it is attached to. The `ViewPager` then checks the value returned by the adapter's `getItemPosition()` for each item, removing those items which return `POSITION_NONE` (see the source code) and then repopulating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

i have find the solution in this post [Remove Fragment Page from ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android)

I have change `FragmentPageAdapter` with `FragmentStatePageAdapater

and Override this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
//FragmentLeft is the class for the first fragment in the view
//recreate only FragmentLeft
    if (object instanceof FragmentLeft) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I propose again the explanation

### Why this solution works

**Overriding getItemPosition():**

When `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called, the adapter calls the `notifyChanged()` method of the `ViewPager` which it is attached to. The `ViewPager` then checks the value returned by the adapter's `getItemPosition()` for each item, removing those items which return `POSITION_NONE` (see the source code) and then repopulating.

Answer (score 1):

1.How you are sending new data to your view pager adapter(i.e SectionsPagerAdapter ).I think you are not sending new data to refresh the adapter

My Suggestion: Please try like this

1. Please create one function(Ex: refreshData(Bundle bundleAdapter)) in adapter(SectionsPagerAdapter) class .
2. so by using that function you can send the new data to adpater from your updateData() method

   1. mSectionsPagerAdapter .refreshData(bundleAdapter)
   2. mSectionsPagerAdapter  .notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: With this procedure the result is the same.
The fragment is updated but remain also the old data.
That is, the fragment is superimposed on the old fragment and you can see overlapping data

Comment: please try with with above logic and remove the logic form notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter.

Comment: i have create the method inside the adapter and delete the notifyDataSetChanged():
`public void refreshData(Bundle bundleAdapter){this.bundleAdapter = bundleAdapter }`

no working for me :(

Comment: Sorry: some spelling mistakes:Please try with above logic....please dont forget to keep my old logic

Answer (score 0):

Please keep my old logic and now remove the default case from getItem() switch case: change the logi like below

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {




        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            FragmentLeft fragmentLeft = new FragmentLeft();
             fragmentLeft.setArguments(bundleAdapter);
                return fragmentLeft;
            case 1:
              FragmentRight fragmentRight = new FragmentRight();
             fragmentRight.setArguments(bundleAdapter);
                return fragmentRight;

        }
    }
```

Comment: nothing and the code is with bug. You must put return outside the switch{}

Comment: Please follow the logic not about return statement.From above code what i want to say that..please don't create the 2 fragment objects unnecesarly. Just create one fragment instance as per your requirement.I mean in case 0: creat leftfragmetn and case 1: create right fragment.

Comment: In defalut case just return null because in your project surely any one the case will execute right.So dont worry about default case of switch.Please let me know you issue done or not.thank you