# ViewPager fragment loads even if the parent Fragment is not active

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

**The background**

I have single activity in my App which loads 2 fragments based on some menu item selection

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            loadFragment(1); // DEFAULT FRAGMENT, AT THE BEGINNING
        }
    }
    ..........................
    ..........................
    // This method is called above, ALSO onItemClick in the Navigation Drawer (code not included for brevity)
    public void loadFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "frag_" + position).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

"Fragment1" is a simple fragment with a fixed text in a TextView. "Fragment2" uses [SlidingTabLayout](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCsfjZ7Z_RAhWCKJQKHUznC9kQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fsamples%2FSlidingTabsBasic%2Fsrc%2Fcom.example.android.common%2Fview%2FSlidingTabLayout.html&usg=AFQjCNE2Ra2Qi2iZSYuL7so1Vb871F-4UQ&sig2=tFX-AQgNaVLM3Inyj6-Mzg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.dGo) to load a Fragment "FragmentViewPager" in a viewpager using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

**The issue I am facing:**

Even if I remove "Fragment2" from the Activity's Frame Layout (using getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove), Fragment "FragmentViewPager" does not get destroyed, rather it resumes every time Activity resumes.

**Question**

Why FragmentViewPager is not destroyed with "Fragment2"?

Comment: Where is the loadFragment() call in Activity

Comment: In two places .. 1) in onCreate method IF savedInstanceState == null ... and 2) In the onClick event on the Navigation Drawer items.

Comment: Okay one more , Where is the FragmentViewPager is lcalled?

Comment: In the ViewPagerAdapter class of Fragment2 (code is included above)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` then this will not destroy fragment and when you swipe and come back to that fragment it will show old data without refresh. Because of not destroyed by viewpager.

Comment: I am not talking about swiping, rather I am removing the "Fragment2" (that contains the viewpager) from activity's frame layout.

Comment: Ok. There is only one way to remove fragment if you have added fragment manually you can refer this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android